# LaTeX (Texlipse) でなぜかfindと打つと出力されない

Tags: eclipse, latex

LaTeXを使うために先日、TexlipseなどをインストールしEclipse上でLaTeXを使えるようにしました。

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum,mathptmx,etoolbox} % Or swap mathptmx with newtxtext,newtxmath
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx} %load extra symbols and environments
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} %set margins
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\title{Mathematics}
\date{}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Introduction}

This project will deal with find

\end{document}
```

こんな感じのコードをとりあえず書いてみたんですが、うまくいかず色々試しましたところ、なぜかfindという文字を文章中に入れたときのみ出力されないようです。pdfが真っ白になり、出てきません。findingの部分をacquiringとかの文字に置き換えるとうまく表示されます。
何が原因かわかりませんので心当たりのある方、回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/texonweb/ で処理させてみたところ想定した PDF が出力されますね。詳細分かりませんが環境依存の問題なようです。

Comment: TeX のログファイル (ﾅﾝﾁｬﾗ.log) に何か警告やエラーは出ていませんか？

Comment: logチェックしましたが、特にfindに関するWarningは出てないんですよね。。。authorがないってことでWarningは出てましたが

Comment: 使用している TeX エンジンは何ですか？ 処理系によっては，たまにエディタ上では表示されない不可視文字が紛れ込んで，それがエラーを引き起こす場合があります．ただ一応 PDF は出力されているということなので，その線は薄いだろうと思っているのですが……

Comment: そういうこともあるので "find" という文字列に一致するかに関わらず，変なエラー・警告がないかよく確認してみてもらうのがいいかなと思います．